How do I avoid Dereference of a possibly null reference?
(Using ASP.NET Core 7 and VS2022)
I have a utility function that I'm bringing over from an old .NET project:
The original looked like this:
public static string WriteString(object str)
{
    if (str == null)
        return "";
    else
        return str.ToString().Trim();
}

I converted it to this:
public static string WriteString(object str)
{
    object s = str ?? "";
    return s.ToString().Trim();
}

But I'm still getting the "Dereference of a possibly null reference" warning. Am I missing something? My variables can't possibly be null, because I'm using the null coalescing operator. So what's bothering VS?

The problem is that Object.ToString() returns a string?

@phuzi which is akward, as "Your ToString() override should not return Empty or a null string."

I asked a question related to this. I wasn't totally convinced by the reasons for allowing ToString() to return null...

As other's have stated Object.ToString() returns string? which could return a null value.
Here's the documentation: Object.ToString
And the actual implementation:
/// <summary>Returns a string that represents the current object.</summary>
/// <returns>A string that represents the current object.</returns>
public virtual string? ToString()
{
    // The default for an object is to return the fully qualified name of the class.
    return GetType().ToString();
}

What you should probably do is check for null at each step falling resorting to "" when any step returns a null value.
public static string WriteString(object str) =>
    str?.ToString()?.Trim() ?? "";

Caveat for .NET Framework
Interestingly the .NET Framework version of `Object.Tostring() method signature is different
public virtual string ToString ();

If you were targetting .NET Framework then your code would not have produced any warnings at all.

Thanks. I knew it didn't throw warnings in .NET, because I'd been using it there with no problems. But your solution works great.

In Visual Studio, if you navigate into Object class definition, you will see the signature of .ToString()
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Returns a string that represents the current object.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     A string that represents the current object.
    public virtual string? ToString();

string? causes str.ToString() to be evaluated to string? and .Trim() can only operate on non nullable string. Technically, you will never get an error, but you might do an extra null check for str.ToString() != null
or you might do str.ToString()!.Trim() just to satisfy the compiler
.NET Framework projects do not produce this warning because signature for .ToString() is different
public virtual string ToString() => this.GetType().ToString();


You're assuming that ToString() will always return a non-null string value here and gambling with a NullReferenceExce[tion. Better to code defensively and check for null at each step.

for me it is 'nah'. if something implements ToString as null or throws an exception, i'd better know it through exception - to be careful with such library in future. by the way, default Rider settings don't produce this kind of warning. maybe there is an exclusion for ToString, not sure

Weird, I do get the "Possible NullReferenceException" warning in Rider.

Hm, I tested on .NET Framework project with nullable - warnings, but if I paste this code in .net 7 with nullable enabled - I get warning as in visual studio

Ah, the method signature is different for .NET Framework... public virtual string ToString ();

ok, thanks, I'll fix my answer

You could do like this:
public static string WriteString(object str)
{
    return s?.ToString().Trim() ?? "";
}

If any of the possible objects in your project might return null as a result of the ToString function, you can add a check for that too, to avoid calling Trim() on a null object:
public static string WriteString(object str)
{
    return s?.ToString()?.Trim() ?? "";
}


What's s and ToString() could still return null!

@phuzi, you're right, I realized that and adapted my answer.

Instead of rewriting all your code to get rid of those warnings, you could also switch off specific warnings in Visual Studio. See this Microsoft article.
A list of all nullable warnings can be found here.

And finally (maybe) create an extension and use a better name:
public static string ToStringTrimmedOrEmpty(this object obj) 
      => obj?.ToString()?.Trim() ?? string.Empty;
    

